# Different design for landscape and portrait orientation android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-screen

Can we have a different xml for landscape and different xml for portrait orientation?

I am working on a simple app, have few buttons and textviews, the xml looks good in portrait, But with same xml when I check the landscape orientation, design doesn't look good.

Any suggestions are appreciated..
Thank you.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes ofcourse.

You will have to create two versions of xml files and put in layout-port and layout-land folder inside res folder.

eg :

```
res/layout [Portrait Mode; default]
 main.xml
res/layout-land [Landscape Mode]
 main.xml
```

You can refer further more on the same at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

Answer (score 5):

If you want to make another layout for landscape then put it in

`res -> layout-land` folder .

Both the names of the xml are must be same for which is used for portrait and landscape .

Comment: Sorry for late reply! Thanks a lot ! :)

Answer (score 1):

you should make a different xml file for landscape orientation. below link can help you

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

Comment: Sorry for late reply! 
Thanks a lot for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_orientation_app);
   if(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels>getResources().getDisplayMetrics().
            heightPixels) 
        {  
            Toast.makeText(this,"Screen switched to Landscape mode",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            Toast.makeText(this,"Screen switched to Portrait mode",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: try to add some explanation rather than just adding code snippet as an answer

Comment: Shouldn't this code be in onStart()? I don't think onCreate() is called when turning the device.

Comment: Al Lelopath, when a device is rotated, the activity is completely removed. OnDestroy is called, then the Activity is restarted. So yes, onCreate is called again