# application of android,not fit on screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to the android application development.My application's layout page not fit on the device screen, it spans than the screen.when i go for the landscape mode then home_imgbtn,msg_imgbtn,chat_imgbtn,like_imgbtn,set_imgbtn take gap between them,not view as the portrait mode.please help me....here is my code..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="STATUS BAR"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:background="@drawable/img1"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            android:textColor="#fffdfb"
            android:textColorHighlight="#fff8f8"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:autoText="false"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"/>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:id="@+id/home_imgbtn"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                android:src="@drawable/img3"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="30"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-2dp"/>

        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:id="@+id/msg_imgbtn"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                android:src="@drawable/img2"
                android:layout_weight="30"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-7dp"/>

        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:id="@+id/chat_imgbtn"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                android:src="@drawable/img4"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="30"/>

        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/like_imgbtn"
                android:src="@drawable/img5"
                android:layout_weight="30"/>

        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:id="@+id/set_imgbtn"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                android:src="@drawable/img6"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="30"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="41dp"
                android:text="My Kicka Details"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="#000100"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="35dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
                android:background="@drawable/img7"
                android:gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Let's help you find the best perks!"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="22dp"
                />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="NAME"
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_column="3"
                        android:textColor="#010101"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="JOHN "
                        android:id="@+id/textView5"
                        android:layout_column="10"
                        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
                        android:textColor="#010101"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:singleLine="false"
                        android:phoneNumber="false"/>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="SURNAME"
                        android:id="@+id/textView6"
                        android:layout_column="3"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
                        android:textColor="#010101"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="20dp"/>

                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="CHATTERJEE"
                        android:id="@+id/textView7"
                        android:layout_column="10"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:textColor="#000100"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="top"/>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="POST CODE"
                        android:id="@+id/textView6"
                        android:layout_column="3"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
                        android:textColor="#010101"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="20dp"/>

                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="742563212"
                        android:id="@+id/textView7"
                        android:layout_column="10"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:textColor="#000100"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="top"/>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="GENDER"
                        android:id="@+id/textView6"
                        android:layout_column="3"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
                        android:textColor="#010101"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="20dp"/>

                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="MALE"
                        android:id="@+id/textView7"
                        android:layout_column="10"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:textColor="#000100"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="top"/>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="D.O.B"
                        android:id="@+id/textView6"
                        android:layout_column="3"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
                        android:textColor="#010101"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="20dp"/>

                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="06/05/1988"
                        android:id="@+id/textView7"
                        android:layout_column="10"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:textColor="#000100"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="top"/>
            </TableRow>




        </TableLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="333dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-70dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

            <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="180dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton15"
                    android:background="@drawable/img15"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="88dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="iAD"
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="35dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/img10"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#fff9f0"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use another layout for landscape mode, for more info see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781449/different-design-for-landscape-and-portrait-orientation-android

Comment: set the screenOrientation to portrait in the manifest of the activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two layouts, one is the default one which will be used by small screen cellphones, and its xml file will be in standard layout folder, the second one would be for tablets and it should be in folder layout-large.

```
For example, the following is a list of resource directories in an application that provides different layout designs for different screen sizes and different bitmap drawables for medium, high, and extra high density screens.

res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

More information go to official documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: i can't scroll on the screen,and also not fit on the screen..please hlp me out...

Comment: @user3201621 if u want scroll your content then you used FrameLayout or LinearLayout (As ScrollView single child) and add all other view into FrameLayout or LinearLayout and then add this FrameLayout into ScrollView. That's it. Try out this and let me know if it's not work.

Answer (score 1):

You should Go with following `Developer website` [Support Mutilple SCreen](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Options you have Got:

1) Create different `Layout` for Different `Screen`

For Ex:

eg :Create the Following Folder as below in to your resource folder

```
res/layout-land [Landscape]

main.xml 

res/layout-port [Portrait]

main.xml
```

Hope this could make you clear...

Answer (score 0):

Put your entire layout in a ScrollView.

If you need vertical space, use ScrollView.
If you need horizontal space, use HorizontalScrollView.
To use [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html).

```
<HorizontalScrollView 
    android:... >
    <..... your current layout ....>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Here is an [example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/horizontalscrollview/android-horizontalscrollview-example/).