# How to change the position of layout when the orientation of screen change in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, orientation, android-orientation

How to change the position of layout when the orientation of screen change  in android ?

I have a button in the `Relativelayout`.

When the phone is `LANDSCAPE`, the `Relativelayout` is at the bottom.

And it turn to the right of screen , when phone is `PORTRAIT`.

It like the following picture.

I get the orientation of screen , but how to setting the `Relativelayout` change it position from bottom to right ?

[image]

----------------------------------EDIT----------------------------

The code of `xml` in `layout-land`.

There are two `button` in `top_buttonlayout1` ,the another two `button` is in `bottom_buttonlayout1`.

The `top_buttonlayout1` is the `Relative-2` in the picture , and the `bottom_buttonlayout1` is the bottom `relativelayout`.

**And I want it change to straight , how to do ?**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_buttonlayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/top_buttonlayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="#00000000" >

           <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/SettingButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:src="@drawable/parmeter_setting" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/FileSavebutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"  
                android:background="#00000000"        
                android:src="@drawable/save_in_camera" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_buttonlayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#454749"
         >

       <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_buttonlayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/FileButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="#454749"
                android:src="@drawable/file_viewer"/>

             <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/photo_record_mode"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"            
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="#454749"
                android:src="@drawable/recordmode"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> You will have to create two versions of xml files and put in
>   layout-port and layout-land folder inside res folder.
>
> eg :
>
> ```
> res/layout-land [Landscape Mode]
> main.xml 
> res/layout-port [Portrait Mode ]
> main.xml
> ```
>
> You can refer further more on the same at
>   http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

source : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781449/different-design-for-landscape-and-portrait-orientation-android)

Comment: How to turn the relativelayout to straight in layout-land ??

Comment: as i said in my answer.make two layout files each for landscape and portrait.And you cant make relative layout straight.you can place views relative to each other.For horizontal or vertical layouts use linear layout.

Comment: I have create the same layout in res/layout-land. But the relativelayout also at the bottom

Comment: in layout-land you have to place button at right of parent according to figure

Comment: I mean...not only the button , I have set the background to Relativelayout. And I want the Relativelayout change from horizontal to straight.

Comment: I have post the code of mxl , please teach me how to turn the layout to straight , Thanks

Comment: Should I need to write the code in JAVA , like if(screen is land){ use layout-land } ???  or it will change auto ?

Answer (score 2):

Create different layout for lanscape and put it under same name in layout-land folder

Comment: I have post the code of mxl in latout-land , please teach me how to turn the layout to straight , Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should create two versions of xml files and put in layout and layout-land folder inside res folder.

somthing like:

```
res/layout-land [Landscape Mode]
main.xml 
res/layout [Portrait Mode ]
main.xml
```

Fore more about layout design visit this link:  http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html