# Error : Execution failed for 'app:mergeDebugResources'

Tags: android, android-resources

I was trying to reposition the textfields and button by using this method:

[How to change the position of layout when the orientation of screen change in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227846/how-to-change-the-position-of-layout-when-the-orientation-of-screen-change-in-an)

but when i try to run it, it returns the following error:

```
Error : Execution failed for 'app:mergeDebugResources'
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
```

> C:\Users\My.Name\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\src\main\res\layout\layout-land: Error: The file name must end with .xml

how should i solve this? the file inside the layout-land folder is already an xml file.

Comment: `The file name must end with .xml`... Read the error

Comment: edited the question. thanks.

Comment: Well, my answer, and the one that you have linked to and should read more carefully should address your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created `res\layout\layout-land`

When you should have created `res\layout-land`.

The **land**scape XML files should be the same name as their counterpart portrait mode files.