# Android remove Popmenu scroll option

Tags: android

In portrait mode when the PopupMenu item is pressed a list of 4 items appear. In landscape mode not all the items are visible and scrolling is automatically enabled. Even though there are only 4 items, and there is definitely enough room on the screen. How do i remove the scroll option?

This is the menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

   <item
       android:id="@+id/menu_userGame_uninstall"
       android:title="@string/userGames_gameMenu_uninstall"/>
   <item
       android:id="@+id/menu_userGame_similarGames"
       android:title="@string/userGames_gameMenu_similarGames"/>
   <item
       android:id="@+id/menu_userGame_share"
       android:title="@string/userGames_gameMenu_share"/>
   <item
       android:id="@+id/menu_userGame_rate"
       android:title="@string/userGames_gameMenu_rate"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create different layouts to support both potratit and landscape mode.

eg :

```
res/layout-land [Landscape Mode]
main.xml 
res/layout-port [Portrait Mode ]
main.xml
```

You can refer further at :

[How do I specify different layouts for portrait and landscape orientations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124046/how-do-i-specify-different-layouts-for-portrait-and-landscape-orientations)

[Different design for landscape and portrait orientation android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781449/different-design-for-landscape-and-portrait-orientation-android)

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

Comment: I dont want different layouts. I want cancel the scroll option.