# Text alignment of a paragraph in Android studio, xml

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-xml

Whenever I have a second line, it's going to the beginning of the screen from left, while I started with a certain space in the first line, because I am trying to write 3 level lines and when the 2nd or 3rd level second line comes back to the beginning of the screen it ruins my organization,
Knowing also that adding space is not a good solution, as when the phone is in landscape, it's showing that space, if I add one

Comment: Try using padding and margins

Comment: margin solved my problem, thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You have to design both portrait and landscape view. Both will use different xml as the screen layout is different. So this will resolve issue for portrait and landscape. And for text starting from beginning try giving margin on that text view.

Follow [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781449/different-design-for-landscape-and-portrait-orientation-android)

Answer (score 0):

please try this :

```
  <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="\t\t\t\t\t\tLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."/>
```