# How to set android TV screen Orientation to portrait mode java/kotlin?

Tags: android, android-tv

i have used this code but it is not working for me `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`
but the output shown like this
[image: Here is the output in emulator]

I want it to fit on the screen like landscape but the content show in portrait mode.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make two type of designs one for portrait mode and another for landscape mode.

```
res/layout [Portrait Mode; default]
 main.xml
res/layout-land [Landscape Mode]
 main.xml
```

Please check the following answer.
Link: [Different design for landscape and portrait orientation android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781449/different-design-for-landscape-and-portrait-orientation-android)